# Is there any way to remove the a post publishers name from user view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, view

Im really confused about certain sharepoint features sometimes, and this is one of them. I was able to remove the main 'Author' of a post when you click on it (underneath the title). However it still shows this published date & author name, which I have yet to find a way to remove from view. Its not needed for my teams case, and I would love some support. Thank you
[image]

Comment: Hi Saad. Are you talking about this page? /_layouts/15/news.aspx ? It's an out-of-the-box application page that can't be customized. You can't hide, show or otherwise edit anything on this system page.